# SQL-инструкция UPDATE в Visual Studio: неопределенная функция to_date

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, access

Пишу запрос на обновление данных в БД в Вижуал студио 2015. В данном запросе мне нужно получить строку DOB и преобразовать ее в дату, но я получаю ошибку "Неопределенная функция to_date в выражении).
Использую С#, СУБД Access. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
    UPDATE Clients
    SET FullName = '@FullName', 
        BirthDate = to_date('@DOB', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 
        Phone = '@Phone', 
        Email = '@Email', 
        Gender = '@Gender', 
        Adress ='@Address'
    WHERE (IDClient  = '@ID')
```

Comment: Ну так реально - нет такой функции. В зависимости от того, как подключаетесь, используйте CDate() или CAST().

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
UPDATE Clients
SET FullName = '@FullName', 
    BirthDate = cDate(Format('@DOB','MM-DD-YYYY')), 
    Phone = '@Phone', 
    Email = '@Email', 
    Gender = '@Gender', 
    Adress ='@Address'
WHERE (IDClient  = '@ID')
```